# How to create a column validation that will not allow salaries higher than $15,000 on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, column-validation

I am trying to create a Data Validation that will not allow salaries **higher than $15,000** on SharePoint 2013.

I can do this perfectly fine in Excel like this: [image] but when it comes to SharePoint it is another story.

How can I do this in SharePoint 2013?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing the right thing. But the input in the SharePoint column "max value" seems wrong. Just write "15000" without the quotes, and the validation should work fine. The thousand seperator will appear anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type "15,000"(English format comma) or "15000" here:
[image]

As per my test, they both worked perfectly in my list. In your case, "15 ,000" is not valid. Change it to "15,000" or "15000"